# Trying to setup a single home video system using webcams on different machines, each running a different OS

Tags: streaming, webcam, video-player

I have four machines, each with a webcam:
 - Mac Mini running OS X El Capitan
 - Dell Precision tower running Windows 10
 - Lenovo IdeaPad running Ubuntu Linux
 - Raspberry Pi 3

So far I have been using TeamViewer to remote into each machine and view the webcam, respectively. Obviously this isn't a very elegant solution. What, if any, software could I use to *combine* the video stream so that I could monitor all my cameras from a single machine? Much thanks.

Comment: On what OS should it run, and how much money you are willing to invest if it comes to paid software?

Comment: I'm fine with pretty much any OS, except really manual/difficult Linux like distros like Arch.